# How to get environment variables based on build environment dynamically in external extconfig.js file in angular

Tags: angular

I have configuration in angular.json file pointing towards different "urls" for different build

## angular.json

```
configuration:{
   'dev':{
      "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
    },
   qa:{

  }
}
```

## environment.dev.ts

```
export const environment = {
 appServer: "https://....."
}
```

## environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
 appServer: "https://....."
}
```

I want to create a extconfig.js file(external js) keeping in assets and putting it in angular.json file

## config.js

```
var baseUrl = '' ; <==========// environment.appServer based on build condition
```

It should serve the purpose of handling "appServer" of environment variables based on build environment when run through either "`ng serve --configuration=dev` or `ng build --configuration=prod`.

This is required beacuse "extconfig.js" file will hold global variables containing configuration variables serving for other external js which may require `baseUrl` for `ajax` call

Comment: I don't understand your problem. How does Angular's environment mechanism not solve your problem? Why can't you just import from environment.ts?

Comment: This is beacuse some external js files require environment variables configuration like "appServer" which may be different for different builds and this is inorder to ensure that when some ajax call is being done in external js file through jquery- this requires "baseUrl" based on env at the time of ajax call.

Comment: Yes - that is what environment.ts is for. It automatically gets replaced during the qa build with environment.qa.ts. I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: Here external js are not aware of environment files and it&#39;s &quot;appserver&quot; key and value when making ajax call through jQuery prefixed with baseUrl ie environment.appserver

Comment: No, and nor should they be. Your app should pass urls into external js files. And also... jQuery?! Nooooo

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding correctly, you can create a `config.prod.ts` and a `config.ts` under the same folder, each one holds a version of your appServer url. then you can import your config from the folder in your services.

`import { extConfig } from './config-specifics';`

`var baseUrl = extConfig.appServerUrl`

and in your `angular.json`.

```
"fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "apps/app-name/src/app/config-specifics/config.ts",
          "with": "apps/app-name/src/app/config-specifics/config.prod.ts"
        }
      ]
```